# pandas fillna sequentially step by step

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, fillna

I have dataframe like as below

```
Re_MC,Fi_MC,Fin_id,Res_id,     
1,2,3,4
,7,6,11
11,,31,32
,,35,38

df1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

I would like to `fillna` based on two steps

a) First, compare only `Re_MC` and `Fi_MC`. If a value is missing in either of these columns, copy it from the other column.

b) Despite doing step a, if there is still NA for either `Re_MC` or `Fi_MC`, copy values from `Fin_id` for `Fi_MC` and `Res_id` for `Re_MC`.

So, I tried the below two approaches

**Approach 1 - This works but not efficient/elegant**

```
df1['Re_MC'] = df1['Re_MC'].fillna(df1['Fi_MC'])
df1['Fi_MC'] = df1['Fi_MC'].fillna(df1['Re_MC'])
df1['Re_MC'] = df1['Re_MC'].fillna(df1['Res_id'])
df1['Fi_MC'] = df1['Fi_MC'].fillna(df1['Fin_id'])
```

**Approach 2 - This doesn't work and provide incorrect output**

```
df1['Re_MC'] = df1['Re_MC'].fillna(df1['Fi_MC']).fillna(df1['Res_id'])
df1['Fi_MC'] = df1['Fi_MC'].fillna(df1['Re_MC']).fillna(df1['Fin_id'])
```

Is there any other efficient way to fillna in a sequential manner? Meaning, we do `step a` first and then based on result of `step a`, we do `step b`

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

**updated code**

```
df_new = (df_new 
 .fillna({'Re MC': df_new['Re Cust'],'Re MC': df_new['Re Cust_System']})
 .fillna({'Fi MC' : df_new['Fi.Fi Customer'],'Final MC':df_new['Re.Fi Customer']})
 .fillna({'Fi MC' : df_new['Re MC']})
 .fillna({'Class Fi MC':df_new['Re MC']})
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dictionaries in [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
(df1
 .fillna({'Re_MC': df1['Fi_MC'], 'Fi_MC': df1['Re_MC']})
 .fillna({'Re_MC': df1['Res_id'], 'Fi_MC': df1['Fin_id']})
)
```

output:

```
   Re_MC  Fi_MC  Fin_id  Res_id
0    1.0    2.0       3       4
1    7.0    7.0       6      11
2   11.0   11.0      31      32
3   38.0   35.0      35      38
```

Comment: but how does it do in order? is that how dict keys work?

Comment: Yes dictionaries are ordered in python since 3.6, so the operations are applied in the order of definition ;)

Comment: @TheGreat I know, it's no blame from my side. But commenting just to say it is unnecessary and is seen as pollution as eventually someone will flag the comment as unnecessary and this gives mods more work to check and delete them. But thanks for you appreciation anyways ;)

Comment: one minor weird issue. When I run the above code, it doesn't fill all NA's in those column at once. So, when I run the jupyter notebook cell again for 2nd time, it fills all NA's. Is there any reason why all NA's for respective columns are not filled at once (instead we have to execute twice)?

Comment: you can see the updated code at the botton of the post to see what I am doing. Is it because of duplicate keys?

Comment: I think it's not unexpected and inherent to the logic. As you fill data the columns change, so when you run the code again you get a new iteration. Example you have 3 cols A,B,C you fill A with B, B with A, B with C. If you have NaNs in a row of both A and B (but not C), you won't fill A until the second iteration.